# Cannot access element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a tbody, which includes 5 rows(for example), when I tried to count number of rows using the following code I received an error:

```
var count = $(".grid-row").length
undefined
count
0
```

Then, I tried `ready()` and received the following:

```
$(".grid-row").ready(function() {    console.log( "ready!" );}); 
// ready!

init [prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: ".grid-row"]
```

Only When I clicked on 2-5 row in the element's tab in Chrome, I could access all 5 rows:

```
$(".grid-row").ready(function() {    console.log( "ready!" );});
// VM1565:1 ready!
// init(5) [tr.grid-row.even, tr.grid-row.odd, tr.grid-row.even, tr.grid-row.odd, tr.grid-row.even, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: ".grid-row"]
```

What I should do in this case in order to count all rows? Thanks.

Comment: The code and printouts you listed are not clear at all, can you edit your question so we can actually understand?

Comment: The table is on the DOM when u execute the event? Give us more information please

Comment: try $(document).ready(function(){ console.log($(".grid-row").length);}) if it's in the DOM the table must works

Comment: Can you provide your html code for that.

Comment: I think DOM elements is not loadded: let tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
undefined
tr
HTMLCollection [], how can i loaded before counting rows?

Comment: Sorry, but i can't provide code

Comment: @JordiJordi I have already tried it, but only 1st row out of 5 is presented, how can i loaded another row?

Answer (score 0):

Put your query in document.ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var count = $(".grid-row").length
});
```

Also, make sure the class name is on the TR element and not the TABLE element.

Comment: I have already tried it, bot only 1 row out of 5 is on DOM, how can i loaded another rows?

Comment: Please post your generated HTML table.  Are your sure all rows have that class name assigned?

Comment: You can also wrap in a setTimout( () => { var count = $(".grid-row").length }, 2000) to determine if this a loading order issue.

Comment: I tried timeout, it does not work, rows have such class:"grid-row even" or "grid-row odd", so i use only "grid-row"

Comment: what happens when you do $("tr").length?

Comment: or document.querySelectorAll('tr').length?

Comment: $("tr").length
6

Comment: Thank, you it works, but why it does not work with class?

Comment: Please post generated HTML then. It sounds like the class name is on wrong element or not set to correct value.  Is it on the table or TD?

Comment: sorry, i reload page, and received the same issue: var x = $("tr").length;
undefined
x
0

Comment: Is your table static, or are you generating it via JS?